# Memory Usage Issue with declared variables (when swapping between states)

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw

So my problem is that When I make a Shader variable and I swap between mainmenustate and gamestate really fast I notice my memory usage increase alot but as soon I switch my Shader varaible into a pointer memory usage dont increase until I put cameraShader = new Shader(); I tried deleting the cameraShader but memory usage still increase

BAREBONE EXAMPLE

```
#include "glfw.h"
#include "glad.h"
#include "Shader.h"
class State{
private:
Shader* cameraShader;
public:
State(glfwwindow* window, std::stack<State*>* states){

cameraShader("example.vs", "example.fs");
}
virtual ~State(){
delete cameraShader;
}
}
void update(float& dt){
}

void render(){
}
```

main

```
  #include "State.h"
  #include "stdafx.h" 
  #include "Game.h"


  void Game::framebufferCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
  {
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  }

  Game::Game()
  :previousTime(0.f), dt(0.f)
  {
  //Variables
  const unsigned int width = 854, height = 480;

  //Initiating GLFW Window
  glfwInit();
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  #ifdef _APPLE_
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  #endif

  //Creating a GLFW window
  window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "EXAMPLE", NULL, NULL);

  //Checking if Window was initiated
  if (window == NULL) {
    std::cout << "GLFW FAILED TO INITIATE WINDOW!\n";
    glfwTerminate();
    }

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  //Setting Window's aspect ratio
  glfwSetWindowAspectRatio(window, 16, 9);

  //Centering Window 
  int windowWidth, windowHeight;
  glfwGetWindowSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
  const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
  glfwSetWindowPos(window, mode->width / 2 - windowWidth / 2, mode->height / 
  2 - windowHeight / 2);



  //Checking if Glad was initiated
  if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
    std::cout << "GLAD FAILED TO BE INITIATED\n";
    }

  //Enabling OpenGl features
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
  //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

 //Setting-Up Viewport
 glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebufferCallback);

//Intitiating MainMenu
 states.push(new MainMenuState(window, &states));
 }

 Game::~Game()
{
}

int Game::glfwGetWindowShouldClose()
{
return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
}

void Game::processWindowEvents()
{
//Calculating Deltatime
double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
dt = currentTime - previousTime;
previousTime = currentTime;
}

void Game::update()
{
processWindowEvents();
if (!states.empty()) {

    states.top()->update(dt);
    if (states.top()->getQuit()) {
        states.top()->endstate();
        delete states.top();
        states.pop();
        std::cout << "States has been deleted\n";
    }
}
else {
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
}

void Game::render()
{
//Clearing display
glClearColor(0.15f, .45f, .60f, 1.f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

if (!states.empty()) {
    states.top()->render();
}

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Shader class

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Shader
 {
  public:
 unsigned int ID;

 Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath, const char* geometryPath = nullptr)
 {
    // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
    std::string vertexCode;
    std::string fragmentCode;
    std::string geometryCode;
    std::ifstream vShaderFile;
    std::ifstream fShaderFile;
    std::ifstream gShaderFile;
    // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
    vShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    fShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    gShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    try 
    {
        // open files
        vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
        fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
        std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
        // read file's buffer contents into streams
        vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
        fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();       
        // close file handlers
        vShaderFile.close();
        fShaderFile.close();
        // convert stream into string
        vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
        fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();         
        // if geometry shader path is present, also load a geometry shader
        if(geometryPath != nullptr)
        {
            gShaderFile.open(geometryPath);
            std::stringstream gShaderStream;
            gShaderStream << gShaderFile.rdbuf();
            gShaderFile.close();
            geometryCode = gShaderStream.str();
        }
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure& e)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
    }
    const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
    const char * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
    // 2. compile shaders
    unsigned int vertex, fragment;
    // vertex shader
    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);
    checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
    // fragment Shader
    fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment);
    checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
    // if geometry shader is given, compile geometry shader
    unsigned int geometry;
    if(geometryPath != nullptr)
    {
        const char * gShaderCode = geometryCode.c_str();
        geometry = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(geometry, 1, &gShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(geometry);
        checkCompileErrors(geometry, "GEOMETRY");
    }
    // shader Program
    ID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
    glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
    if(geometryPath != nullptr)
        glAttachShader(ID, geometry);
    glLinkProgram(ID);
    checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
    // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
    glDeleteShader(vertex);
    glDeleteShader(fragment);
    if(geometryPath != nullptr)
        glDeleteShader(geometry);

}
// activate the shader
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void use() 
{ 
    glUseProgram(ID); 
}
// utility uniform functions
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
{         
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value); 
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
{ 
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value); 
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
{ 
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value); 
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setVec2(const std::string &name, const glm::vec2 &value) const
{ 
    glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]); 
}
void setVec2(const std::string &name, float x, float y) const
{ 
    glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y); 
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setVec3(const std::string &name, const glm::vec3 &value) const
{ 
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]); 
}
void setVec3(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z) const
{ 
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z); 
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setVec4(const std::string &name, const glm::vec4 &value) const
{ 
    glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]); 
}
void setVec4(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z, float w) 
{ 
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z, w); 
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setMat2(const std::string &name, const glm::mat2 &mat) const
{
    glUniformMatrix2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setMat3(const std::string &name, const glm::mat3 &mat) const
{
    glUniformMatrix3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setMat4(const std::string &name, const glm::mat4 &mat) const
{
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
}

private:
// utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, std::string type)
{
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[1024];
    if(type != "PROGRAM")
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog;
        }
    }
}
};
    #endif
```

Comment: Could it be that your Shader class is missing a dtor with a call to `glDeleteProgram`?

Answer (score 1):

Shader need a:

1. [Copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)
2. [Move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)
3. [Copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)
4. [Move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment)
5. [Destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

For stop leak videocard memory.
You call glCreateXxxx and you should call glDeleteXxxx on destruction.
https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/